# Did a change stop .tagged-interesting from working on Firefox?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching

Today, it looks like something changed that stopped custom colors for my watched tags from working in the Stack Overflow question list. I use Firefox and for the past few years I have used:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix("http://stackoverflow.com"), url-prefix("https://stackoverflow.com") {
  .tagged-interesting {background-color: #272727 !important;}
}
```

This provided a contrast in the normal list of questions for tags I follow. That just stopped working. Is this intentional, and what can I do to recover contrast for tags I follow? Without contrast, it makes it much more difficult to find relevant questions quickly.

Comment: Uber Meta dupe: [Ignored and watched tags seem broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366321) | It affects ignored tag styling as well.

Comment: I noticed the same thing on Chrome.

Comment: The system built-in highlight for interesting questions is also broken. It looks like there is no .tagged-interesting class any more. It seems to work on the mobile version but not on the desktop.

Comment: Cause is identified; fix is en-route: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366345/23354

Comment: Is it just me or is the highlighting still not working even though this issue has been marked as completed?

Comment: @CodyGray Why is this status-completed? I understand that a fix is planned, but it's still not been implemented / rolled out.

Comment: I can confirm no roll-out, I've about gone blind squinting to read the tags `:)`

Comment: @Scratte Marc marked [the MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366321) as status-completed, which suggests that he *did*, in fact, roll out the change.

Comment: @CodyGray I guess Marc missed it on [Stack Overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo92l.png).. :(

Comment: @Scratte Looks like it's working on the `/questions` page but not on the home page. That goes for all sites, not just SO. Marc [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/ignored-and-watched-tags-seem-broken#comment1220917_366345) he'll be checking it on Monday.

Comment: SO started working fine again this morning. Good job. Gives you a whole new appreciation to the role record contrast can play when reading long lists....